# Is this picture of a differential $1$-form correct?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Consider the following picture of $x dy$:

[image]

(this picture appears in [this article](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/828035/Mathematics/forms.pdf)).

I believe these lines should be vertical:

At each point in $\mathbb R^2$  a basis for the tangent space is given by $dx, dy$. If $x$ and $y$ are the coordinates (local but in this case they are also global) then a point in $\mathbb R^2$ is given by $(x,y)$.

To get a basis for the tangent at a point one applies the partial derivatives and then evaluates at the point giving:

$$ dx = {\partial \over \partial x} (x,y) = (1,0)$$

and

$$ dy = {\partial \over \partial y} (x,y) = (0,1)$$

Then

$$ x dy = (0,x)$$

Which seems to me should be a vertical line.

> What am I doing wrong? Please could someone help me understand this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing an important point: the coordinate differentials $dx$ and $dy$ are (at each point) a basis of the *cotangent space*. What you are doing is identifying both spaces via the canonical inner product of $\mathbb R^2$, and saying $dy \mathrel{\hat=} \partial_y$. But then you miss an important point, namely that there is an important difference between forms and vectors. Their geometrical interpretations are straight lines (forms) and directed lines/arrows (vectors). Hence in your picture, the lines doesn't have arrows at the end!

To make this picture clear, let us leave differential geometry behind, because this is **not** the essential ingredient here and only complicates things. Let us consider some vector space $V$ and its dual space $V^*$. Vectors $v\in V$ have a straight geometric interpretation: They are elements of the vector space and can be identified with directed line segments going from the origin 0 to $v$. But how can we interpret forms $f\in V^*$? These are linear maps $f:\,V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and hence as long as $f\neq 0$, their kernels always have codimension 1. Hence it seems kind of natural to take this subspace as the geometric interpretation of $f$. Since its codimension is 1, it divides $V$ in half-spaces $f\leq 0$ and $f\geq 0$.

Back to the original setting: Here we have $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ and hence the mentioned kernels are 1-dimensional. Additionally, we now have to deal with differential forms and vector fields, which is essentially the same, except that we have to make every concept point-wise.

We want to compute the kernel of dy. The action of $dy$ on a vector field $X=X_x \partial_x + X_y \partial_y$ is given by $dy(X) = X_x dy(\partial_x) + X_y dy(\partial_y) = X_y$, so it picks out the $y$ component of $X$.$^1$ Then the solution of the equation $dy(X)=X_y=0$ are those vector fields which are proportional to $\partial_x$. This means that at each point, the kernel of $dy$ is just the $x$ axis of the tangent space.

Finally, this is why we identify $dy$ with horizontal lines. Since $dy$ and $f(x,y)dy$ would result in the same line, we could say that we use a horizontal line, starting at $(x,y)$ which is $|f(x,y)|$ long and end up with your picture.

$^1$ Alternatively, this can be computed using the inner product via $dy(X) = \langle \partial_y, X \rangle = X_y$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I'm still confused and need a little bit more help: It seems to me that you are confirming what I wrote. If $dy$ picks out the $y$ component it seems to me that $x dy$ would be a vertical line. It's really not clear to me. When you write for example $dy$ do you implicitly mean the line that is the kernel of the derivative with respect to $y$?

Comment: The point is that you can identify vector fields and differential forms if you have metric - this is essentially the same as identifying $V$ and $V^*$ after having chosen an inner product. But these two objects have a totally different geometrical interpretation in the first place. Besides this, if $dy$ picks out the $y$ component, $dy=0$ means that your vectors only have $x$ components, so point in $x$ direction. See my edited posts for some more details about the geometry of dual spaces.